# Cannot read property 'register' of undefined after installing inert in hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I started working with Hapi framework of nodejs. I am using Hapi "version": "16.0.0". I was trying to load static pages and content with Hapi and for that i installed "inert" plugin with the help of command `npm install --save inert`.
Here is my code which i included in my server.js file as given below.

```
    server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        server.route({
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/hello',
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                reply.file('./public/hello.html');
            }
        });
    });
```

After running project with `node server.js` I am getting following error.

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/pro_hapi/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:219
        if (plugin.register.register) {                             // Required plugin
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
    at module.exports.internals.Server.internals.Plugin.register (/Library/WebServer/Documents/pro_hapi/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:219:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/pro_hapi/server.js:16:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched for that and i found a solution which conclude following things

1. Installing inert plugin with command `npm install inert --save` will install inert version 5.x by default.
2. Inert version 5.x has breaking changes for hapi v17 support. That means for `hapi "version": "16.0.0",` like I am using will need to use `Inert v4.x`  or, to use Inert v5 you will need to update to hapi v17.
3. For installing npm older package version we need to run following command. `npm install <package>@<version>`

In my case i run `sudo npm install inert@4.2.1 --save` which overwrite existing inert package(5.x) with inert version 4.2.1.

4. Finally I again run my project with `node server.js` and this time it worked.